Optimization problems with softmax [reference request]
It is well known that many common machine learning models can be formulated as mixed-integer linear programs. Well... that's if you ignore the softmax at the end (or, in the binary classifier case, the logistic function). For example, a logistic regression is just a linear model but for the final logistic transformation. Another example is a neural network classifier with ReLu is a MILP, as each neuron looks like $relu(x) = max(0,x)$, which is of course MILP-representable -- but for the final softmax layer.
In this MILP formulation you can do some interesting things like testing robustness of the ML model to perturbations by solving a MILP optimization/feasibility problem. For properties like robustness of a classifier, it suffices to check the values before the softmax, i.e., the logits, as you can just check whether the logit of a given class is greater than or equal to all the other classes as your robustness condition. There are a few tools that can do such encodings, including a recent Python package from Gurobi called gurobi-machinelearning.
However, what if I want to work with the actual probabilities? E.g. if I want to verify a property like: the probability of a class is bounded between two values. Then I need to encode softmax into my program. One way, of course, is some piecewise-linear approximation: e.g., Gurobi has GRB_GENCONSTR_LOGISTIC, which will construct such an approximation of the logistic function.
But I am interested in other work on approximations or relaxations of softmax. I would appreciate any references or pointers to methods for solving optimization programs with softmax.

In the binary classifier case, the softmax function simplifies to a sigmoid. For example, if we wanted to distinguish red vs blue, we would have one linear signal, $\theta^T x$, where we could interpret 0.1 as a weak preference to red and -10 as a strong preference to blue. The probabilities would then be
$$
p_{red} = \sigma(\theta^T x),\quad p_{blue} = 1 - p_{red} = \sigma(-\theta^T x).
$$
We would like to maximize the likelihood of correct predictions:
$$
\max \prod_{i \in red} p_{red} \cdot \prod_{i \in blue} p_{blue},
$$
but since this is not representable in convex optimization, we instead maximize the log-likelihood. In this answer I will further flip the sign to minimize:
$$
\min \sum_{i \in red} -\log(p_{red}) + \sum_{i \in blue} -\log(p_{blue}),
$$
and we are now within the realm of convex optimization because
$$
-\log(\sigma(u)) = -\log\left(\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-u)}\right) = \log(1 + \exp(-u)),
$$
is a common disciplined convex programming expression known as the softplus. This approach generalizes to the multiclass case, wherein the logarithm of the softmax probabilities are represented similarly. Note that the binary classifier example above, appears in the MOSEK Cookbook after introduction of the exponential cone.

Nice, very interesting! And thanks for the Mosek link.
